# Wikipedia module python: jumping "wikipedia.exceptions.PageError"

Tags: python, csv, wikipedia

I'm trying to associate to each species name listed in a csv file the wikipedia summary and main image.
I write this code:

```
import csv
import wikipedia

wikipedia.set_lang('it')

with open('D:\\GIS\\Dati\\Vinca\\specie_vinca.csv', 'rt', encoding="utf8") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        wikipage = wikipedia.page(row)
        print (wikipage.title)
        print (wikipage.summary)
        print ("Page URL: %s" % wikipage.url)
        print ("Nr. of images on page: %d" % len(wikipage.images))
        print (" - Main Image: %s" % wikipage.images[0])
        print ("")
```

but each time it doesn't encounter a species name the script stops wiht this message "wikipedia.exceptions.PageError".
How can I skip these records leaving the script finish?

Comment: may be it is empty value exception.file have content or not

Comment: You can use `Try: Except` to skip those errors and let the script finish.

Comment: Thanks. @Fabio Lamanna

Comment: plaese mark it.the answer is corect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `wikipedia.page` will raise a `wikipedia.exceptions.PageError` if the page doesn't exist. That's the error you want to catch.

I will give you an example://maybe its useful to you

```
import wikipedia
links = ["CPython","no page"]
test=[]
for link in links:
    try:
        #try to load the wikipedia page
        page=wikipedia.page(link, auto_suggest=False)
        test.append(page)
    except wikipedia.exceptions.PageError:
        #if a "PageError" was raised, ignore it and continue to next link
        continue
```

> **IMPORTANT NOTE**:You can use `Try`: `Except` to skip those errors and
>   let the script finish

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much @bob marti