# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip' after update wikipedia module

Tags: python, wikipedia

After resolving the question: ["Wikipedia module python: jumping “wikipedia.exceptions.PageError”"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42110203/wikipedia-module-python-jumping-wikipedia-exceptions-pageerror)

with this code:

```
import csv
import wikipedia

wikipedia.set_lang('it')

with open('D:\\GIS\\Dati\\Vinca\\specie_vinca.csv', 'rt', encoding="utf8") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        try:
            wikipage = wikipedia.page(row)
            print (wikipage.title)
            print (wikipage.summary)
            print ("Page URL: %s" % wikipage.url)
            print ("Nr. of images on page: %d" % len(wikipage.images))
            print (" - Main Image: %s" % wikipage.images[0])
            print ("")
        except wikipedia.exceptions.PageError:
        #if a "PageError" was raised, ignore it and continue to next link
            continue
```

I have update the wikipedia module to 1.4.5 for python 3.6.
Now the code doesn't work for : "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'"
I don't understand why before it worked and now no.
How can I resolve it?

CVS file contains name of species:

```
...
Acmaeops septentrionis
Aconitum anthora
Aconitum lamarckii
Aconitum lycoctonum
Aconitum napellus
Aconitum paniculatum
Aconitum vulparia
Acorus calamus
Acrida ungarica
Acritus minutus
Acritus nigricornis
...
```

Comment: But you feed the `wikipedia.page` a **list**, not a single item.

Comment: What’s the format of the CSV?

Comment: It's a file text with 1 column of names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a csv reader, a `row` is **a list of elements**. Indeed for each column there is an element. Now you pass the **entire list** to the `wikipedia.page(..)` method?

You can resolve it by for instance extracting the first element of the row and fetch that page:

```
wikipage = wikipedia.page(row[0])
```

So you use `[0]` to **get the first column** of that row.